# Dealing with conditionally-executed SELECT statements

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have this sp: using sql server 2008

```
create procedure SelectTopCounts
    @Id bigint = null,
    @Count int = null,
    @GetAll bit = 0
as
begin
    set nocount on

    IF (@Count IS NULL)
        SELECT @Count = 15 --default

    if(@GetAll = 1) 
       begin
           select col,col2... .......
           --very long select statement...
       end
    if(@Count is not null)
       begin

           select top @count .....
           --very long select statement...
       end
```

Is there a way I can have only ONE select statement instead of duplicating within the `if and else` condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table will always have <= 2 billion rows, replace all the IFs/ELSEs with this:

```
SELECT TOP(COALESCE(CASE @GetAll WHEN 1 THEN 2000000000 END, @Count, 15))
  col1, col2
FROM ...
-- I assume the @Id comes into play somehow...
-- WHERE ID_column = COALESCE(@Id, ID_column);
```

Comment: Just a high upper limit on the TOP() command (that's why I said as long as your table will always have <= 2 billion rows - it's essentially the same as saying TOP 100 PERCENT or leaving out the TOP to return all rows). Technically you should probably use 2147483647.

Comment: thanks i realized after i post my question... i will test it.